"error": "Couldn't create User: ERROR: of relation \"users\" violates not-null constraint
I'm creating rssagg app
this is the error i got
{
  "error": "Couldn't create User: ERROR: null value in column \"id\" of relation \"users\" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)"
}

this is my handler user go function
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype"
    internal "github.com/sakthi-lucia0567/rssagg/internal/database"
)

func (apiCfg *apiConfig) handleCreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type parameters struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    params := parameters{}

    err := decoder.Decode(&params)
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, 400, fmt.Sprintf("Error parsing JSON: %v", err))
        return
    }

    userUUID := uuid.New()
    // generatedType := pgtype.UUID{Bytes: userUUID[:]}
    generatedType := pgtype.UUID{Bytes: userUUID, Valid: true} // this is the code that chatgpt gave but it's seems it's also not working for me. 
    log.Println("user uuid", userUUID)
    log.Println("user generated type", generatedType)
    user, err := apiCfg.DB.CreateUser(r.Context(), internal.CreateUserParams{
        ID:        generatedType,
        CreatedAt: pgtype.Timestamp{Time: time.Now()},
        UpdatedAt: pgtype.Timestamp{Time: time.Now()},
        Name:      params.Name,
    })
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, 400, fmt.Sprintf("Couldn't create User: %v", err))
        return
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, 200, user)
}


this is my models.go generated by the sqlc
// Code generated by sqlc. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//   sqlc v1.26.0

package internal

import (
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype"
)

type User struct {
    ID        pgtype.UUID
    CreatedAt pgtype.Timestamp
    UpdatedAt pgtype.Timestamp
    Name      string
}

user.sql.go
// Code generated by sqlc. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//   sqlc v1.26.0
// source: users.sql

package internal

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype"
)

const createUser = `-- name: CreateUser :one
INSERT INTO users (id, created_at, updated_at, name)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
RETURNING id, created_at, updated_at, name
`

type CreateUserParams struct {
    ID        pgtype.UUID
    CreatedAt pgtype.Timestamp
    UpdatedAt pgtype.Timestamp
    Name      string
}

func (q *Queries) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, arg CreateUserParams) (User, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRow(ctx, createUser,
        arg.ID,
        arg.CreatedAt,
        arg.UpdatedAt,
        arg.Name,
    )
    var i User
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.CreatedAt,
        &i.UpdatedAt,
        &i.Name,
    )
    return i, err
}

this is the log i get while running the server:
2024/04/11 00:56:22 user uuid 18bd07ce-a47d-484a-b2d3-1b1fb8d2bf9e
2024/04/11 00:56:22 user generated type {[24 189 7 206 164 125 72 74 178 211 27 31 184 210 191 158] false}

i'm expecting to creating a user but the uuid is coming as a Bytes
the uuid is generating but i couldn't set them to postgres id

Please edit your question to include the table definition SQL.

Please also edit the quesion to show the code that actually interacts with the database (presumably this is the body of CreateUser).

i briefly explained the problem as much i could please help.
i tried these also
var userUUIDBytes [16]byte
copy(userUUIDBytes[:], userUUID[:])
generatedType := pgtype.UUID{Bytes: userUUIDBytes, Status: pgtype.Present}
but no use same error coming
  "error": "Couldn't create User: ERROR: null value in column \"created_at\" of relation \"users\" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)"
}```

pgtype.UUID is defined as (assuming that you are using PGX v5):
type UUID struct {
    Bytes [16]byte
    Valid bool
}

So when you assign with pgtype.UUID{Bytes: userUUID} the value of Valid will be the default (false; and you can see this in your output). PGX types work in the same way as the sql package Null types (e.g. NullBool); that is if Valid is false then the value will be treated as a NULL when sent to the database.
To fix this use:
generatedType := pgtype.UUID{Bytes: userUUID, Valid: true}

You will need to use a similar approach with pgtype.Timestamp.
Note: This is based on the info you provided (I've made assumptions about what apiCfg.DB.CreateUser does).
